# how to get the videos(urls) in listview?

Tags: android, url, listview, video

I'm new to android domain..

I'm working with small app..
In my app im using `youtube` videos to play in `video view`..

What i need is ??

I have `youtube` videos urls in a array list. I want this `array list` of videos should show in `listview`(thumbnails) with text and if the user select the video it should play in next full screen..

How to implement this?? please help me..

I have went through google but still i didn't clear example..  Please any one help me..

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Use `custom adapter` with `Imageview` and `Textview`  , `Imageview` for `thumbnail` and `Textview` for video name . and use `listitemclicklistener`

Comment: can you give example for this...but in my array i have stored the urls..

Comment: @OneManArmy: come http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27387/android-india

Comment: @OneManArmy Please also parse Name of the youtube video and display that name into the list. When user click on that list, it will open the requested URl and play video.

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    try {
         url="http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url="www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwGHJJYBs0Q"&maxwidth=500";
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.v("URL request", "--->" + url);
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        String changeTIDRec = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        System.out.println(changeTIDRec);
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(changeTIDRec);
        Log.v("WebService", "Response : " + jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonResponse;





    JSONObject json = new WebService().RequestUrl(url);
            String thumbnail_url;
    if (json == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String provider_url = json.getString("provider_url");
        System.out.println("provider_url"+provider_url);
        String description = json.getString("description");
        System.out.println("description"+description);
        String title = json.getString("title");
        System.out.println("title"+title);
        String urls = json.getString("url");
        System.out.println("url"+urls);
        String thumbnail_width = json.getString("thumbnail_width");
        System.out.println("thumbnail_width"+thumbnail_width);
         thumbnail_url = json.getString("thumbnail_url");
        System.out.println("thumbnail_url"+thumbnail_url);
        String version = json.getString("version");
        System.out.println("version"+version);
        String provider_name = json.getString("provider_name");
        System.out.println("provider_name"+provider_name);
        String type = json.getString("type");
        System.out.println("type"+type);
        String thumbnail_height = json.getString("thumbnail_height");
        System.out.println("thumbnail_height"+thumbnail_height);
}
    return thumbnail_url;
```

Example

http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFBdW9EQgVg&maxwidth=500

thumbnail url :http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/KFBdW9EQgVg/hqdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

take look at this example from [github](https://github.com/blundell/YouTubeUserFeed)

 and for more

I have used this code in my application and played videos into Webview using Html code iframe tag.