# change White background during app launch

Tags: android

I want to get rid of the white color during the short period when my app is launching but the content isn't displayed, yet.

My main activity is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kam.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

how can replace white background to progress bar ?

**Update :-** 
mainfest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kam.StartPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kam.MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/loading" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.67" />

</LinearLayout>
```

startpoint.class

```
public class StartPoint extends Activity{

ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                while(progressBarStatus < 5000){
                    StartPoint.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run()
                        {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            progressBarStatus += 1000;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, com.example.kam.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainList);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

i will try but when open loading image and open main layout its show error

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android

Comment: @nirav can u answer this [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292956/how-to-get-the-videosurls-in-listview ]

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara but its without thread how can i do it with thread

Comment: @kammaik: come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27387/android-india

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara any help

Comment: @kammaik: are you fetch data from web services ?

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara i don't have any web service ?? explain !!!

Answer (score 0):

There a many [tutorials](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen) and [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdIG7kYjYbE) for creating Splash Screens, which should give you the desired results.

The basic steps are;

1. Create a splash image in the desired drawables folders.
2. Create a theme with your image in it
3. create an activity using the theme, and have that activity start your current main activity

Comment: You would do this before you do anything.  You make this your first activity, then it calls your current first activity, which would have your thread in it.  Perhaps I'm not understanding you.